# Paste decimal value using Application.InputBox

Tags: vba, excel

I am assigning values to three cells (inspecao, alpha and lambda).
This code works fine for integers numbers assigned, but not for decimals.

For < 1 numbers or decimals, Excel writes zero instead.

```
Dim alpha as Double
Dim inspecao As Double
Dim lambda As Double

inspecao = CInt(Application.InputBox("Insira o intervalo de inspecao:", Type:=1))
alpha = CInt(Application.InputBox("Insira o parametro alpha:", Type:=1))
lambda = CInt(Application.InputBox("Insira o parametro lambda:", Type:=1))

Range("E1").Value = inspecao
Range("I2").Value = alpha
Range("L1").Value = lambda
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weber, That's because you're casting everything as `CInt`. Just remove that and you'll be fine:

```
    Dim alpha As Double
    Dim inspecao As Double
    Dim lambda As Double

    inspecao = Application.InputBox("Insira o intervalo de inspecao:", Type:=1)
    alpha = Application.InputBox("Insira o parametro alpha:", Type:=1)
    lambda = Application.InputBox("Insira o parametro lambda:", Type:=1)

    Range("E1").Value = inspecao
    Range("I2").Value = alpha
    Range("L1").Value = lambda
```

Comment: Copied this part of code from a website long ago and didn't even looked further! haha Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck with your project!